# i have initialized a variable with zero at the top of the function so during a loop the value changes?

Tags: java, arrays, sum, sub-array

```
public class maxsubarraysum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numbers[] = { 1, -2, 6, -1, 3 };
        printmsasum(numbers);
    }

    public static void printmsasum(int numbers[]) {
        int currsum=0;//declared and initialized
        int maxsum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            int start = i;
            for (int j = i; j < numbers.length; j++) {
                int end = j;
                 currsum = 0;                    //here is what i dont understand why i have to again give it zero to run it properly what its is called ? means am i missing any concept? pls help in loops does value changes?
                for (int k = start; k <= end; k++) {
                    currsum += numbers[k];
                }
                System.out.println(currsum);
                if (maxsum < currsum) {
                    maxsum = currsum;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("the maximum sub array sum is = " + maxsum);
    }

}
```

i tried it with only declaring and initializing the currsum variable with zero ,then the output is wrong then inside the second nested loop why i have to initialized it with zero for correct answer?

Comment: Leaving your question aside for a second, you don't need to declare `currsum` where you did. Instead, declare it where you're setting it to 0.

Comment: From what I can see, you have to reset currsum variable, because it does change in nested for loop. Also, you could declare & initialize currsum inside your for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring cursum in the function so its scope is the entire function, which contain all the loops.  It will not be reset to 0 on entering your inner loop as its scope is outside of that loop.

You could just move its declaration inside the second loop, right before your "k" loop. That will restrict its scope to the iteration over k which looks to be the partial sum you want.

That would be replacing your

```
cursum = 0;
```

with

```
int cursum = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing `currsum` in every iteration `currsum += numbers[k];`, so to check every new result, you have to reset the `currsum`. You don't have to declare it before loops, you can actually declare it in the same place you are setting it to 0.

Tip: You also don't have to initalize `start` and `end` variables, you can use `i` and `j`

Comment: Please notice "declare" and "initialize" are two separate things. `int i;` is a declaration, `int i = 0;` is a declaration **and** initialization. In this context "declare" would be more appropriate, since `int currsum = 0` is not only an initialization.